# Redirect loop on authentication after token expiry using react-aad-msal

Tags: reactjs, azure, redirect, azure-ad-msal

I've attempted to replace ADAL with MSAL. The first time the user accesses the app it authenticates correctly, but I am getting into a situation where our app goes into a redirect loop after a period of time. I presume this is when the token expires (1 hour by default, I believe). This happens sometimes when the app is idle after an hour, which is why I think it may be to do with the way a new token is obtained as well as when I refresh the browser window.

** AuthProvider.ts **

```
import { Configuration } from 'msal

// Msal Configurations
const config = {
   auth: {
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_TENANT,
      clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_CLIENT_ID,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      redirectUri: window.location.origin,
      validateAuthority: true,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
   },
   cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // This configures where your cache will be stored
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
   },
} as Configuration

// Authentication Parameters
const authenticationParameters = {
   scopes: ['openid', 'api://' + process.env.REACT_APP_AAD_SCOPES],
}

// Options
const options = {
   loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
   tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html',
}

export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)
```

then when calling our api, I thought I could call the getAccessToken method like below and I would silently receive a valid token, but I just end up in a redirect loop.

I'm wondering why it works the first time the user accesses the app, but not when trying to refresh the token. I would think the Azure config is correct, since it works the first time. Could it be an iframe / browser issue or is it a code problem?

[![IdResponse tokenType undefined][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vkwn.png

Comment: Any news about this issue? I'm experiencing same problem and provided answer is not much of a help.

Comment: Any updated with this issue? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

To Acquire a valid token using refresh token you need to call msal.js token API acquireTokenSilent. For more information on how to get acquire a token using msal.js refer [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-acquire-token?tabs=javascript).

You can refer the msal.js [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-v2) for your scenario.

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_eEBA247w4smeEIZ&Q_CHL=gl
>

Comment: @InspiredJason May i know the reason why there is a downvote for the answer ? did it not answer your question ?